# Save xml to files in SQL Server

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server-2012

Is it possible to save XML content to files directly from SQL Server 2012?

Given data like this:

```
DECLARE @xmlTable TABLE 
(
    ID INT,
    XmlDescription VARCHAR(100),
    XmlContent Xml
)

INSERT INTO @xmlTable 
VALUES(1, 'XmlDescription1', '<randomXml randomAttribute="value"><randomChild /></randomXml>'),
      (2, 'XmlDescription2', '<someOtherXml someOtherArribute="value" />'),
      (3, 'XmlDescription3', '<somethingElse somethingElseAttribute="value" />')

SELECT * FROM @xmlTable
```

I want to create 3 different files in my file system for each of these xml data.

The file names are taken from the `XmlDescription` column, i.e. the created xml files should be `XmlDescription1.xml`, `XmlDescription2.xml` and `XmlDescription3.xml`.

Comment: I am on a dev machine, which is not the one hosting SQL server. But I have access to server if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible via SQL Server FILESTREAM feature. You can save any files you want on a disk using it. But, you will lose the ability to query your XML files from SQL queries. You'll have to deal with them (parsing, etc.) in your application.

Also, as of SQL Server 2012 you can use the [File Tables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff929144%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) feature (here you can even handle filenames).